# Nine patches are not loaded correctly - libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, progress-bar, loading, nine-patch

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:
http://bitowl.de/day11/

I downloaded the images(full.png, empty.png) into my workspace and I tried to load them in my code exactly as it described but from some reason the nine patch of the full bar is not loaded.

Here is my code:
http://i.gyazo.com/9e012807bc761a27cb696f78d8c32aed.png

And here is the result:
http://i.gyazo.com/2390151a40f7986b20ea1731b7e15d6d.png

What can be the reason for this problem?

P.S I tried to draw fullbar(texture region) in my code and it works well(except that it doesn't scale nicely at all)

Comment: Never mind guys. I have found the solution. It turns out I had to define the variables that way: `emptybar = new NinePatch(emptybarT,8,8,8,8);
  fullbar = new NinePatch(fullbarT,8,8,8,8);`

Comment: for future reference:  please don't provide screenshots for your code but the relevant parts as text in the question.  It is also perfectly fine on SO to provde your own answer.  so others with a similar problem see a possible solution right away